# Logout and Delete Cookies [Redirect to main page]

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, logout

When user clicks the logout button from the main page, the cookies will be deleted and they will be redirected to window.location = url; . Even if user does not login, but instead clicks logout, they will still be redirected to window.location = url;. My codes are as below, I can't seem to logout even if I click the logout button and I will stay at the main page while being logged in. Can anyone tell what is wrong? I am new to JavaScript and I need help regarding this topic.

```
$('.logout-btn').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  if(isset($_COOKIE['REFERER']) && $_COOKIE['REFERER'] != '') {
    window.location = url;
  }
  else {
    $.post(outurl, function( data ) {
    }).then(function(r){
      $('#popup_ok, .x-close').bind( "click", function() {
        window.location = url;
      });
      if(r.result == 1){
        popup_msg('Failed', r.msg);
      }
      else{
        popup_msg('Success', r.msg);
        setTimeout(function(){
          window.location = url;
        },2000);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

try this code this will execute when user close the tab or close the browser it will automatically destroy session and cookies stored

```
<body onbeforeunload='destroySession()'>
</body>


<script type='text/javascript'>
function destroySession()
{
    $.ajax({
       url: 'process/logout.php'
 });
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Where should i place this codes? What I want is when the user clicks logout, they will be redirected to the window.location = url; not when they close the tab or browser

Answer (score 3):

logout.php

```
 <?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['id']);
header("location:../login.php"); 
?>
```

specify the path of your file at place of login.php